# Force HTTP version of homepage (block HTTPS)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a homepage that requires loading from an `http` source. This generates security warnings when customers visit the `https` version of the homepage. I would like to make sure that the customer cannot get to the `https` version. I think this can be accomplished by some sort of rewrite or redirect in the .htaccess file, but I'm not sure exactly how.

The server is running apache and is set up to use seperate `httpdocs` and `httpsdocs` directories.

There is also no reason that the customer would need a secure connection to the homepage. They are transferred to a secure connection when checking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]
```

This will **always force http** on home page only.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working quite right. It's adding a "%" at the end of the url.

Comment: Curious, does this work (without generating an error) in all browsers?

Comment: Yes it will work across the browsers since even before serving any non-secured content Apache will send a 301 to browsers and browsers will then then send `http://` request to Apache.

Comment: Don't the clients connecting to 443 expect an SSL connection? Or do all of them fail gracefully when they only see HTTP? This may not work through some proxies.

Comment: There's a comment on the first answer that seems logical. Would be interested in finding out if it's true. "Phil is correct. https ://standardhttponlysite won't work. It tells the browser to try using ssl AND do so on port 443. http :// standard:443 would work. But only if the remote site is configured to serve unencrypted traffic over that port. Arbitrary Internet sites won't be."

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase and install an SSL cert from a trusted source.

Because SSL/TLS negotition happens before HTTP, you can't use HTTP redirect to port 80. Furthermore, any clients connecting to port 443 will be expecting an SSL/TLS connection to be established.

Even if you want to only redirect to port 80 (HTTP), you need to purchase a cert in order to redirect without the insecure warning.